# How to resample a column by id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like:

```
id    date    value

1   16-12-1     9
1   16-12-1     8
1   17-1-1      18
2   17-3-4      19
2   17-3-4      20
1   17-4-3      21
2   17-7-13     12
3   17-8-9      12
2   17-9-12     11
1   17-11-12    19
3   17-11-12    21
```

The only structure above is that the rows are sorted by date.

What I want to do is, group by id and resample the dates, so that each id has the same number values. A monthly, weekly or daily resampling would suffice.

My final dataset (at yearly resampling) would look like:

```
id    interval           value

1   16-12-1 - 17-12-1     75
2   16-12-1 - 17-12-1     62
3   16-12-1 - 17-12-1     33
```

How to implement this? Will this work (since I do not have the seconds in the date field, i.e. it is not a standard pandas datetime object)?

```
dataframe.groupby(id).resample('year')
```

Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: It appears that you are looking for the minimum and maximum date in the `interval` column. The `value` column comes from a standard `GROUP BY`. Could you please explain what the re-sampling must accomplish? i.e. what information do you require in the `interval` column?

Comment: @edesz thanks, as in the final dataset snapshot above, the intervals will be the same for all id  e.g. [16-12-1 - 17-12-1] for everyone. the resampling groups the values at say, weekly intervals. so, by resampling i intend to have the same number of values for each of the id. The resampling will be between the maximum and minimum dates of the interval column, in order to make every id have the same number of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weekly sum by id:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('date')
df.groupby('id').resample('W')['value'].agg('sum').loc[lambda x: x>0]
```

Output:

```
id  date      
1   2016-12-04    17
    2017-01-01    18
    2017-04-09    21
    2017-11-12    19
2   2017-03-05    39
    2017-07-16    12
    2017-09-17    11
3   2017-08-13    12
    2017-11-12    21
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks, will pd.to_datetime directly work with this date format? I tried it earlier and it didn't work. the dates in your example above also look wrong, e.g. 16-12-1  is supposed to be 2016 - 12 - 1 , year - month -date

Comment: Then you have some bad dates in your data.... You could use errors='coerce' to get nulls for all bad data.

Comment: You can also use format to explicitly define the format to use in pd.to_datetime.  Infact, if you do defined the format it will perform even faster.

Comment: thanks, also will first setting the index and then converting to date time be faster?

Comment: the code is very slow, and takes 5 hours on a million rows, any way to speed it up?

Comment: No, not really.  You might have look at a pure numpy solution, or maybe using dask.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Attempt (with re-sampling)**

Generate data

```
d = [['id', 'date', 'value'],
    [1, '2016-12-1', 9],
    [1, '2016-12-1',8],
    [1, '2017-1-1',18],
    [2, '2017-3-4',19],
    [2, '2017-3-4',20],
    [1,'2017-4-3',21],
    [2, '2017-7-13',12],
    [3, '2017-8-9',12],
    [2, '2017-9-12',11],
    [1, '2017-11-12',19],
    [3, '2017-11-12',21],]
df = pd.DataFrame(d[1:], columns=d[0])

print(df)
    id        date  value
0    1   2016-12-1      9
1    1   2016-12-1      8
2    1    2017-1-1     18
3    2    2017-3-4     19
4    2    2017-3-4     20
5    1    2017-4-3     21
6    2   2017-7-13     12
7    3    2017-8-9     12
8    2   2017-9-12     11
9    1  2017-11-12     19
10   3  2017-11-12     21
```

Yearly re-sampling followed by sum

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.drop('date',axis = 1, inplace = True)
df_g = df.groupby('id').resample('y').sum()
df_g.drop(columns=['id'], inplace=True)

print(df_g)
               value
id date             
1  2016-12-31     17
   2017-12-31     58
2  2017-12-31     62
3  2017-12-31     33
```

**INITIAL answer (without re-sampling)**

You could do this, but it does not perform an explicit `resample` operation

```
f = {'date':['min','max'],
    'value':'sum'}
df_grouped = df.groupby(['id']).agg(f)
df_grouped.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df_grouped.columns.values]
df_grouped.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)

print(df_grouped)
   id  date_min date_max  value_sum
0   1   16-12-1   17-4-3         75
1   2    17-3-4  17-9-12         62
2   3  17-11-12   17-8-9         33
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not resampling as you said, plus different id have different intervals. please see the reply to your comment. thanks.